# Determine which StoryRange the insertion point is in

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to determine which of the 11 StoryRanges the cursor is in.

Can someone tell me the VBA code that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this code:

```
Debug.Print Selection.StoryType
```

As a result you get the number which refers to [WdStoryType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff844990%28v=office.14%29.aspx).